# Formula of Squaring Sums / Integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to find a proof for the identities (which I use quite often) 
$$\left ( \int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx \right )^2=\int_{a}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x, y)\,dx\,dy$$
and similarly for the series
$$\left ( \sum_{k=a}^{\infty}a_n \right )^2=\sum_{m=a}^{\infty}\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}a_{m, k}$$

If someone could prove them or give a link, because I can't find them anywhere.. would be nice.
Thanks!

Comment: How did $f$ become a function in 2 variables? Should it be $f(x)f(y)$ instead of $f(x,y)$? And similarly, should it be $a_m a_k$ instead of $a_{m,k}$?

Comment: Yes! I write it a little quick ... Sorry for that!

Comment: Unless you are billed by the letter, please avoid improper abbreviations like "Thnx" etc. If you are billed by the letter, find a better ISP.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the following:
\begin{align}
\left(\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx \right)^2 
&= \left( \int_a^{\infty} f(x) dx \right) \left( \int_a^{\infty} f(y) dy \right)\\
&= \int_a^{\infty} \left( \int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx \right) f(y) dy \\
&= \int_a^{\infty} \int_a^{\infty} f(x)f(y)dxdy.
\end{align}
The same principle holds in the discrete case:
\begin{align}
\left( \sum_{n=a}^{\infty} a_n \right)^2 
&= \left( \sum_{m=a}^{\infty} a_m \right) \left( \sum_{n=a}^{\infty} a_n \right)\\
&= \sum_{m=a}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{n=a}^{\infty} a_n \right) a_m \\
& = \sum_{m=a}^{\infty} \sum_{n=a}^{\infty} a_m a_n.
\end{align}